# Parameter-free $\alpha$-recursivity versus weakened Turing machines with oracles

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-numbers

In the quest to find a transfinite extension of recursivity which matches intuition, mentioned also in [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451816/simple-alpha1-recursive-well-orders-with-order-type-alpha-text-recursi), Discord user onion5 came up with an idea that expressed precisely how I thought about "computable operations" on ordinals:

Let $M$ be an oracle Turing machine (without the oracle, i.e. it's just a set of instructions for interacting with the tape and the oracle). For $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, we will use $M(X)$ to denote the machine $M$ with the oracle for $X$. Now, for countable infinite ordinals $\alpha$, we define $f_M(\alpha)$ in the following way: If there exists a $\beta$ such that for all well-orders $X$ of $\mathbb{N}$ with order type $\alpha$ (encoded as subsets of $\mathbb{N}$), $M(X)$ computes a well-order of order type $\beta$, then $f_M(\alpha)=\beta$, otherwise $f_M(\alpha)=0$. Finally, let $\delta_{TM}(\alpha)=\text{sup}(\{f_M(\alpha) : M\text{ is an oracle Turing machine}\})$.

An ordinal is parameter-free $\alpha$-recursive iff it is the order type of a well-order definable in $L_\alpha$ by a $\Delta_1$ formula without parameters. Let $\delta_{pf}(\alpha)=\text{sup}(\{\beta : \beta\text{ is parameter-free }\alpha\text{-recursive}\})$.

The main question is: Is $\delta_{TM}(\alpha)$ equal to $\delta_{pf}(\alpha)$ for all infinite countable $\alpha$? And if not, is there any other equivalent definition of $\delta_{TM}(\alpha)$ only in terms of Gödel's constructible hierarchy and set-theoretic formulae of some complexity (e.g. $\delta_{TM}(\alpha)=\alpha^+$ or $\delta_{TM}(\alpha)=|\alpha\text{-recursive}|$)?

Requiring the same order type to be computed using every well-order of order type $\alpha$ should ensure that the machine uses no information from the oracle other than $\alpha$ itself, which is why I believe this definition finally captures the idea perfectly. If we only chose a specific well-order, there would also be the issue of choosing one with a small enough Turing degree, and even then, the Turing machine can sort of use "parameters" - it can use specific ordinals below $\alpha$ because each natural number corresponds to a given ordinal. But that is not allowed in this definition where it has to give the same order type for every well-order, because the natural numbers will represent different ordinals depending on the well-order.

Note that if we let $\delta'_{TM}(\alpha)$ be the supremum of ordinals $\beta$ such that for every well-order $X$ of $\mathbb{N}$ with order type $\alpha$, there is an $M$ such that $M(X)$ computes a well-order of order type $\beta$ (swapping the order of the quantifiers of $X$ and $M$ would give $\delta_{TM}(\alpha)$), then we have $\delta'_{TM}(\alpha)=\alpha^+$, because it is just $\omega_1^{CK}(\alpha)$ from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2363361).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to prove anything specific about how it relates to the constructible hierarchy, and I don't even know where to start, so I'm asking for help here.